# Retrieving attribute value from XPath matching another attribute value from the same node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, .net-3.5, xmldocument

I am trying to read the value of an attribute, checking for the value of another attribute. Below is the content of the xml I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="default" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}${message}${exception:format=tostring}" fileName="${basedir}/logs/Test24x7.txt" archiveAboveSize="999000" maxArchiveFiles="100" archiveEvery="Day"/>
    <target name="f7" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}${message}${exception:format=tostring}" fileName="${basedir}/logs/Errors/error.txt" archiveAboveSize="300000" maxArchiveFiles="100" archiveEvery="Day"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" appendTo="f0"/>  -->
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" appendTo="default"/>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Error" appendTo="f7"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Here, I need to get value of the attribute archiveAboveSize from the element target that has the value of name attribute as "default". Below is the code I wrote.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.exe.nlog");
 var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//nlog/targets/target[@name = 'default']/@archiveAboveSize");
 return node.Value;
```

But I am getting null for the variable node all the time. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML to get the desired attribute value.

Using this line:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.exe.nlog");
```

you can load the XML file, and then query it using:

```
var res = doc.Descendants()
             .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "target")
             .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "default")
             .First()
             .Attribute("archiveAboveSize").Value;
```

Note the usage of [**`LocalName`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This is due to a namespace being used in your xml file.